# Filepicker s3 custom folder under bucket

Tags: filepicker.io

We are trying to use Filepicker.io to upload our user submitted photos to S3. But looks like filepicker does not allow uploading to custom folders within one bucket.

What we have is the following structure.

Bucket_Name/category/username/file.jpg

Usernames are done by each user on our site.

Why is this not allowed?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make use of the `path` parameter on the filepicker.store() call (https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#store):

```
filepicker.store(input, {path: 'category/username/file.jpg'},
    function(new_fpfile){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(new_fpfile));
    }
);
```

Comment: i'm triyng to create structure like this "Bucket_Name/category/username/file.jpg" and if i use path parameter it adds random prefix to first folder instead of filename. after this there are a lot of folders like [prefix-1]-somecategory, [prefix-2]-somecategory, [prefix-3]-somecategory etc. Can you tell me how to disable this prefix on the admin console?

Comment: The prefix is intentional so that collisions are prevented, for example if two users upload "test.png" the second will overwrite the first.

Comment: Thats why we have sub folders by username and a filename of our choosing. Can this be disabled?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the prefixing behavior you're seeing regarding adding a prefix to the first folder rather than the filename, do you have any code you can share to reproduce the issue?